# cloud9, cannot install php cURL

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl, cloud9

I'm trying to execute my php script with a Curl request in cloud9.
When I run, I have this Exception:

**"Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'php function "curl_init" is missing' in /home/ubuntu/workspace/test.."**

I tried to install curl with `sudo apt-get install php-curl` 
or `sudo apt-get install php5.5-curl`, 
also with "ppa:ondrej/php" repository.

Curl package seems to be installed successfully in the cloud9 virtual machine, but it hasn't been enabled in my php.ini.

Comment: Tested today and working on c9.io Why negative vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this works for you:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Ubuntu, use

```
$ sudo apt-get install php-curl
```

This will install 'php7.2-curl' as at 16/05/2019.

Comment: Seems more like configuration issue than installation issue. I ran that command a minute ago and successfully installed cUrl. Run phpinfo(); and verify installation.

Comment: Since OP already tried that with no success, please do not hesitate to suggest any other ideas.